# jinja2 flask escaping jinja2-highlight

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to render some code in a web page, with highlight. I'm using Flask and found that I could use [jinja2-highlight](https://github.com/tlatsas/jinja2-highlight). It works great, but I have some problems.

What I tried :

```
{% highlight 'python' %}
    {{ item.text }}
 {% endhighlight %}
```

Seems to work, I have my 40 lines of code but all special char like &#34 ... are displayed as this. So I add the |safe to the line {{ item.text }}. And now, all char are ok, but I don't see my full code, only 5 lines (the fifth line is complete).

I think I know what is the problem but don't know hw to solve it.

I have some line in my code like  or  and it seems that it's not escaped. Any idea why jinja2 does not escape <> ?

I'm not clear about security question with the |safe too. What does the server risks ?

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? [This pull request](https://github.com/tlatsas/jinja2-highlight/pull/1) addressed over-eager escaping; it would apply to Flask as it enables auto-escaping (a good idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.text|safe` should help. It appears that you're escaping the code twice. You may have some kind of auto-escape enabled.

You don't have to care about the server safety, as long as you don't share your actual code of your site.

Comment: item.text|e does not work. I think it's correctly escaped because I have things like " &#34;" but I get them as this in my html page. Why they are not translate back to '"' ? Maybe it's jinja2-highlight which makes errors.

Comment: You should only worry if the shared server-side code has security vulnerabilities. By exposing the code you allow everybody to examine the vulnerable parts of code and to find out  possible ways to attack your server.

Comment: `|e` **adds** escaping. Perhaps you meant `|safe` instead?

Comment: I tried that, it works for 5 first lines. When I get a line with a <title> in it, as it's not escaped, it's read as an html tag. And content is not displayed. Any idea ?

Comment: Probably you have somehow enabled the 'autoescape' option.

Comment: Ok, I found away to make it works, but there is surely better. I need to change manually all my '<' to &lt; and '>' to '&gt;' with a replace in my python code. But the thing is I can't use |e because it will escape '"' too, which are ok like that and not with |e. It there a way to enable a |* just for '<' and '>' ?

Comment: And you answer the question about risks of server